# How to insert 'NULL' values in int array column into PostgreSQL database using Python

Tags: python, sql, arrays, postgresql

I have this department table which has an array int column.

```sql
create table department(id int,name text, emp_id int[])
```

I'm getting this error for the below statement while inserting data via Python.

```py
my_cursor.execute(
    """
    insert into department
    select 10, 'QC', array[34,62,Null]
    """
)
```

The error is

```
psycopg2.errors.NullValueNotAllowed: array must not contain nulls
```

But I can insert a Null value in array and can run this SQL insert statement in SQL Client or PG Admin

```sql
insert into department
  select 10, 'QC', array[34,62,Null]
```

I think this error is coming from the python module, as the DB allows inserting Null values in SQL statement.

How can we insert `Null` values in `emp_id` column through Python?

Comment: Don't store such an array in the first place. This is a very serious design problem that makes querying, indexing and modifications a lot harder. An integer array is meant to store a bunch of numbers, not FK values to another table. The *department* table shouldn't have to be modified when an employee moves from one department to another. Never mind employees that may work in multiple departments. What about employees having multiple relations with departments, eg `works in`, `temporarily assigned to` ?

Comment: I can't reproduce.  It fails with a different error `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "qc" does not exist`.  And once single quotes are added around QC then it works fine.

Comment: I'm not able to insert `array[Null]` , testing in DBeaver

Comment: @NikhilVJ See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rX4JWYsZ) sql, where null inserted into table in array column.